# For hclust1a-->dendrogram-->hclust1b in R, why plot for hclust1a and hclust1b differs?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust, ggdendro

I have a hclust object named `hc1a`. I convert it to a dendrogram object, which is in turn converted back to a hclust object and name it as `hc1b`:

```
# Create hc1a and plot
hc1a <- list()
hc1a$merge <- matrix(c(-8, -9,
                      -1, -2,
                      -5,  1,
                      -7,  2,
                      -3,  4,
                       3,  5,
                      -4,  6,
                      -6,  7), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
hc1a$height <- c(0.01333333, 0.02000000, 0.03833333, 0.05500000, 0.06888889, 0.10555556, 0.13285714, 0.19625000)
hc1a$order <- c(4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6)           
hc1a$labels <- c(4136, 4137, 4139, 4141, 4292, 4302, 4303, 4305, 4306)
class(hc1a) <- "hclust" 
plot(hc1a)
```

[image]

```
# Create hc1b and plot
hc1b <- as.hclust(as.dendrogram(hc1a))
plot(hc1b)
```

[image]

Why does dendrogram for `hc1a` and `hc1b` differ? How to preserve the structure of dendrogram for `hc1a` in `hc1b`? That is to say, I want to convert `hc1a` to a dendrogram object and convert that dendrogram object back to a new hclust object named `hc1b`. When `hc1b` is plotted, I want it to be identical to `plot(hc1a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order changes when using `as.dendrogram` and `as.hclust`, so you could use the same order of your hc1a object like this:

```r
# Create hc1a and plot
hc1a <- list()
hc1a$merge <- matrix(c(-8, -9,
                       -1, -2,
                       -5,  1,
                       -7,  2,
                       -3,  4,
                       3,  5,
                       -4,  6,
                       -6,  7), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
hc1a$height <- c(0.01333333, 0.02000000, 0.03833333, 0.05500000, 0.06888889, 0.10555556, 0.13285714, 0.19625000)
hc1a$order <- c(4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6)           
hc1a$labels <- c(4136, 4137, 4139, 4141, 4292, 4302, 4303, 4305, 4306)
class(hc1a) <- "hclust" 
plot(hc1a)
```

[image]

```r
# Create hc1b and plot
hc1b <- as.hclust(as.dendrogram(hc1a, check = TRUE))
hc1b$order = hc1a$order
plot(hc1b)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your approach preserves node order when converted to dendrogram object, which is in turn converted back to hclust object. I wonder if it is possible to retain the node order and label for the dendrogram object. Here is the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073949/plot-dendrogram-object-converted-from-hclust-while-preserving-order