# Plot dendrogram object converted from hclust while preserving order

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend

Here is a hclust object named `hc1a` and I want to convert it to a dendrogram object and plot it.

```
# Create hc1a and plot
hc1a <- list()
hc1a$merge <- matrix(c(-8, -9,
                      -1, -2,
                      -5,  1,
                      -7,  2,
                      -3,  4,
                       3,  5,
                      -4,  6,
                      -6,  7), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
hc1a$height <- c(0.01333333, 0.02000000, 0.03833333, 0.05500000, 0.06888889, 0.10555556, 0.13285714, 0.19625000)
hc1a$order <- c(4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 5, 9, 8, 6)           
hc1a$labels <- c(4136, 4137, 4139, 4141, 4292, 4302, 4303, 4305, 4306)
class(hc1a) <- "hclust" 
plot(hc1a)

# Convert hc1a to a dendrogram object and plot    
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc1a)
plot(dend)
```

The order of nodes in the two plots differ. A further check of order and nodes:

```
> order.dendrogram(dend)
[1] 6 4 5 8 9 3 7 1 2
> labels(dend)
[1] 4302 4141 4292 4305 4306 4139 4303 4136 4137
> 
> hc1a$order
[1] 4 3 2 1 7 5 9 8 6
> hc1a$labels
[1] 4136 4137 4139 4141 4292 4302 4303 4305 4306
```

I want to know why both order and labels are changed? How to plot the dend so that it has the same structure as `plot(hc1a)`, i.e., the same node order, label, and the same tree.

Comment: Why are you trying to build the hclust manually?

Comment: I see this is unsual but this is due to a special need for my data analysis.

Comment: Any idea on how to preserve the dendrogram structure when using as.dendrogram()? Thank you.